# Where to write to files android

Tags: java, android, file

I am creating an app where I need to read in a file, possibly make changes and write back. At the moment I have the initial file in assets and it reads in fine, I have just found out however that you cannot write to that location. I want to write to internal storage.

Where should I write a file to so that my app can write on the phone and access the file?

I keep getting various different errors with different implementations: the following provides me with

filenotfound exception: EROFS read only file system

```
public void write(Entry[] newEntries){
 try {
   FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("combinationswrite.txt"));
   OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
   for (int j = 0; j < newEntries.length; j++){
      if (newEntries[j] != null){
       osw.write(newEntries[j].symbol);
       osw.write("\t");
       for (int i =0; i<6; i++){
        osw.write(newEntries[j].getNode(i));
        if( i < 5)
         osw.write(",");
        else
         osw.write("\n");
       }
      }
   }
   osw.flush();
   osw.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

when trying the following implementation in the docs:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

openFileOutput method is not recognised

Answer (score 0):

from the link you refer to let your code like this

```
 public void write(Entry[] newEntries){
     try {
       FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream( getTempFile(context , "combinationswrite.txt"));
       OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
       for (int j = 0; j < newEntries.length; j++){
          if (newEntries[j] != null){
           osw.write(newEntries[j].symbol);
           osw.write("\t");
           for (int i =0; i<6; i++){
            osw.write(newEntries[j].getNode(i));
            if( i < 5)
             osw.write(",");
            else
             osw.write("\n");
           }
          }
       }
       osw.flush();
       osw.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }

public File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {
    File file;
    try {
        String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
        file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
    catch (IOException e) {
        // Error while creating file
    }
    return file;
}
```

this method `getTempFile` will return your file from intarnal storage